# what more can I do to prevent myself from XSS injection & SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, xss

If my site ever goes live (don't think it will, its just a learning exercise at the moment).

**I've been using mysql_real_escape_string(); on data from POST, SERVER and GET.
Also, I've been using intval(); on strings that must only be numbers.**

I think this covers me from *sql injection*? Correct? Can i do more?

But, I'm not sure how it provides (if it provides any protection at all) from *XSS injection*?

Any more information on how to combat these two forms of attacks is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to believe, but you can get nearly 1000 answers with more information on how to combat these two forms of attacks, if you bother to use a search box at the top of this page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think this covers me from sql injection? Correct?

No. It makes a terrible mess of your data.

> Can i do more?

Yes. You can protect your code from SQL injections.
Here is **[a brief explanation I've made already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)**
Only I have to add that you should not spoil your source data arrays.
POST array has noting to do with SQL. The data may go into email, an HTML form, a file, online service, etc. Why treat it all with SQL protection?
On the other hand, you may take your data not from POST but from a file, online service, other query.
So, you have to protect not source arrays, but **actual data that goes into query**

Speaking of XSS, there are no simple universal rule again.
But in general, you have to use `htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES);` for the every untrusted data you output as a text, and some other kinds of validations in some special cases, like filenames

Answer (score -1):

Used hard coded prepared queries